# How to only display rows without a specific word in spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco, tibco-topic

Below is the dataset. I want to display only the rows that doesn't have "confidential" in the description column in spotfire. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

@Chitra- In *data table properties > Limit data using expression*, insert the below expression to filter out rows which contains 'confidential' in column Test.

```
not(Lower([Test])~='confidential')
```

**Here is the final output:**

[image]

Hope this helps!