# How to remove rows based on conditions

Tags: spotfire

I need to remove some rows from a table when the data is imported into spotfire, please see the table in the screenshot
[image]

if the field Qualified != PASS (including blank and FAIL ), this row should be removed from this table

how to meet this need?

Comment: Do you want the data removed from a visualization, or removed when the data is imported into spotfire?

Comment: Hi Scsimon, i need remove them when these data is imported into spotfire, i also updated my question

Comment: @user1994358- Why don't you use limit data using expression in the table? Please check this SO post on how it works - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875941/how-to-only-display-rows-without-a-specific-word-in-spotfire/47889054#47889054

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you access the data through a database connection, then you could apply your loading condition in the data-on-demand dialog.

If it's an Excel spreadsheet, I can think of a couple options:

(1) Add a tab in Excel and write a formula to copy from your main data tab using "Qualified" as a condition for copy; use this copied tab for importing to Spotfire... could also do this with an Excel macro

(2) Go with @user1994358 suggestion to apply the condition directly to your visualizations. For any visualization, go to Properties>Data>Limit data using expression>Edit and use the following expression (keeping in mind Spotfire is case sensitive).

```
[Qualified] = "PASS"
```

This statement will exclude all rows in the visualization that do not meet this condition.